# How do I prove this (limit and series)?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $$a_{n+1} = a_n + ca_n^2 \quad \forall n \in N_+,$$ where $c$ is a positive constant. Show that

$$(1) \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$$
$$(2) \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac 1{1 + ca_i} = \frac 1{ca_1}$$

My try:

I have already solved the first by observing that $$a_{n+1} = a_n + ca_n^2 \gt a_n$$ and thus $$a_{n} \ge a_1(1 + ca_1)^{n - 1} \quad \forall n \in N_+.$$

For the second I observed that $$1 + ca_i \gt ca_1(1 + ca_1)^{i - 1}$$ and thus $$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac 1{1 + ca_i} \lt \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac 1{ca_1(1 + ca_1)^{i - 1}} = \frac 1{ca_1} + \frac 1{c^2a_1^2}.$$

I guess I'm close to the answer, but I can't see how to proceed.

Comment: What is known about $a_0$? Note that if it is 0, then the whole sequence is identically zero, so none of the conclusions hold.

Comment: @mathguy I suppose the clue is $a_1$ is a positive real number.  $a_0$ is never used or defined.

Comment: Same thing, what is known about $a_1$? If it's 0, then... Etc.

Comment: @mathguy They're all positive real numbers.

Comment: @mathguy All $a_n$ are positive precludes $a_1=0$.

Comment: Oh, I missed "positive" in the text of the problem, my mistake!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a telescopic series.$$
\frac{1}{a_{i+1}}=\frac{1}{a_i(1+c\,a_i)}=\frac{1}{a_i}-\frac{c}{1+c\,a_i}.
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{1+c\,a_i}=\frac{1}{c\,a_i}-\frac{1}{c\,a_{i+1}}.
$$

Comment: So for these "telescopic series" similar techniques are used, right? Thank you! Learned something new today.